# Show that $\int x \mu(dx)=0$ when $\mu$ is the "limit" of a sequence of measures.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of measures and $\mu$ any measure defined on the borelians of $\mathbb R^n$. Denote $\mathcal C_\mu$ the class of continuity sets of $\mu$ -- i.e. $\mu(\partial (A))=0$.  Suppose:
$$\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A)\quad  \forall A\in \mathcal C_\mu,\,\, 0 \notin \bar{A} \quad  (n \to \infty)$$
Here, $\partial (A)$ and $\bar A$ are the topological boundary and topological clousure of $A$, respectively. Moreover, suppose that
$$\int x \, \mu_n (dx)=0  \quad \forall \, n \in \mathbb N.$$

I want to show
$$\int x \, \mu (dx)=0$$

Is this true? Or do I need other hypotheses?

Some ideia how to show it?

Comment: Interested in $\mu_n,\mu$ being probability measures, or the general case? Where do you use $\mathcal{C}_\mu$?

Comment: I am interested in the general case. Do you think this only holds for probability measures? I edited the question specifying where I use $\mathcal C_\mu$

Comment: No, but the setting could have a straightforward probabilistic interpretation though. Is the measurable space of reference $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B})$?

Comment: The measures are defined on the borelians of $\mathbb R^n$. I believe the one-dimensional case must be a particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even for probability measures you can cook up counterexamples to your claim. Let $\mu_n = \frac 1n \delta_{-n+1} + (1- \frac 1n)\delta_1$. Then $\mu_n$ converges in the sense you describe to $\delta_1$.

The additional hypothesis you need would be some kind of uniform integrability, such as proving that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M>0$ such that $\int_{|x|>M} |x| \mu_n(dx) <\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to prove it! If I can't, I'll edit this question. If so, I accept the answer.

Comment: If you edit because you need additional help, comment on my answer so I get a notification. Cheers.

Comment: I came to review this question and saw that I had committed the impoliteness of not accepting your answer. A thousand apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize, happy to help.